# Connection reset in sockets

Tags: java, sockets, socketexception

I have a game like blackjack that I have a server and players. When I execute the server and the players in the same computer it works perfect. But when I execute the players in one pc and the server in another pc it works so rare. After some writebytes from server and some readLines from users it gives me "Java.net.SocketException: Connection reset".

Why is this happening?

```
            Socket registre = null;

            try{
                registre = new Socket(IP,port);
            }
            catch(java.net.ConnectException e){
                System.out.println("Servidor de partida incorrecte.");
                break;
            }
            catch(java.net.UnknownHostException e){
                System.out.println("Servidor de partida incorrecte.");
                break;
            }
            catch(java.net.SocketException e){
                System.out.println("Servidor de partida incorrecte.");
                break;
            }

            DataOutputStream sendToServer = new DataOutputStream(registre.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader receiveFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(registre.getInputStream())); 

            numCartes = 2;

            sendToServer.writeBytes("JUG"+"/"+portJug+ '\n');

            boolean llistaJugadors = false;

            servidorJoc = receiveFromServer.readLine().trim();
            System.out.println(servidorJoc);
            System.out.println("----------------------------------");

            while(!llistaJugadors){

                servidorJoc = receiveFromServer.readLine().trim();

                if (servidorJoc.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")){
                    llistaJugadors=true;
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println(servidorJoc);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("----------------------------------");

            boolean jocAcabat= false;               
            jugant = true;
            boolean canviant = false;
            String torn=null;
            boolean unCanviEfectuat=false;

            torn = receiveFromServer.readLine().trim(); 
            System.out.println(torn);

            String[] jug = torn.split("-");
            jugador = jug[1];
            jug = torn.split(":");
            float puntuacio = Float.parseFloat(jug[1]);

            if (puntuacio>=7.5){
                jugant=false;
            }

            while (!jocAcabat){

                if (canviant==false && jugant){
                    torn = receiveFromServer.readLine().trim();
                    System.out.println(torn);

                    if (llegirMes==1){
                        String[] infor = torn.split(":");

                        float passat = Float.parseFloat(infor[1]);

                        if (passat>=7.5){
                            jugant=false;
                            System.out.println("T'has passat amb puntuacio: "+passat);
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (llegirMes==1){
                    torn = receiveFromServer.readLine().trim();
                    System.out.println(torn);
                    llegirMes=0;
                    canviant=false;
                }


                String[] data = torn.split(":");

                if(data[0].trim().equalsIgnoreCase("torn") && jugant){

                    ImprimirMenu2();

                    fet=false;
                    int conf=0;

                    while (!fet){
                        try{
                            conf = Integer.parseInt(teclat.readLine());
                            if(conf<4 && conf>0){
                                fet=true;
                            }

                        }
                        catch(NumberFormatException e){
                            System.out.println("Intrudueix un enter entre 1-3");
                        }

                    }

                    switch (conf){

                    case 1:
                        canviant = false;
                        sendToServer.writeBytes("CARTA+" + "\n");
                        receiveFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(registre.getInputStream())); 
                       torn = receiveFromServer.readLine().trim();  <----CRASH
                        System.out.println(torn);
                        String[] puntuacion = torn.split(":");
                        float punt = Float.parseFloat(puntuacion[1]);
                        if (punt>=7.5){
                            jugant=false;
                        }
                        unCanviEfectuat=false;
                        numCartes++;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        canviant = false;
                        sendToServer.writeBytes("TREE" + "\n");
                        receiveFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(registre.getInputStream()));  
                        torn = receiveFromServer.readLine().trim();     <----CRASH
                        System.out.println(torn);
                        jugant = false;
                        unCanviEfectuat=false;
                        break;

                    case 3:

                        if (unCanviEfectuat){
                            System.out.println("Ja has fet un canvi aquest torn, no pots fins el seguent.");
                            break;
                        }
                        else{
                            canviant = true;
                            System.out.println("Introdueix la ip del jugador: ");
                            llegit = false;
                            String ip = teclat.readLine();
                            int portJugador = 0;
                            System.out.println("Introdueix el port: ");

                            while(!llegit){

                                try{
                                    portJugador = Integer.parseInt(teclat.readLine());
                                    llegit=true;
                                }
                                catch(NumberFormatException e){
                                    System.out.println("Has introduit un valor incorrecte.");
                                }
                            }

                            Socket conectarjugador = null;

                            try{
                                conectarjugador = new Socket(ip,portJugador);
                            }

                            catch(java.net.ConnectException e){
                                System.out.println("Jugador incorrecte");
                                break;
                            }

                            catch(java.net.UnknownHostException e){
                                System.out.println("Jugador incorrecte");
                                break;
                            }

                            catch(java.net.SocketException e){
                                System.out.println("Servidor de partida incorrecte.");
                                break;
                            }

                            BufferedReader receiveFromJugador = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conectarjugador.getInputStream())); 

                            String info = receiveFromJugador.readLine().trim();

                            if (info.equalsIgnoreCase("estic plantat!")){
                                System.out.println("El jugador es troba plantat. No pot canviar Cartes.");
                                break;
                            }
                            else{

                                if (info.equalsIgnoreCase("deny.")){
                                    System.out.println("El jugador no vol fer el canvi.");
                                    break;
                                }

                                else {
                                    System.out.println("El jugador ha acceptat el canvi, procedim a efectuar els canvis.");

                                    info = receiveFromJugador.readLine().trim();

                                    String[] informacio = info.split(":");
                                    int cartaCanviarJug2 = Integer.parseInt(informacio[0]);
                                    String jugadorCanvi = informacio[1];

                                    unCanviEfectuat=true;

                                    min =0;
                                    max = numCartes-1;
                                    rand = new Random();
                                    int cartaCanviar = rand.nextInt((max-min)+1)+min;

                                    sendToServer.writeBytes("CHANGE:"+jugador+":"+cartaCanviar+":"+jugadorCanvi+":"+cartaCanviarJug2+ "\n");

                                    info = receiveFromServer.readLine().trim();

                                    informacio = info.split(":");
                                    float passat = Float.parseFloat(informacio[1]);

                                    if (passat>=7.5){
                                        jugant=false;
                                        System.out.println(info);
                                        System.out.println("T'has passat amb puntuacio: "+passat);
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        System.out.println(info);
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }

                else {

                    jugant=false;
                    boolean noAcabat=true;
                    while (noAcabat){

                        try{
                            torn = receiveFromServer.readLine().trim();     
                        }
                        catch(java.net.SocketException e) {
                            return;
                        }
                        System.out.println(torn);
                        data = torn.split(":");

                        if (data[0].equalsIgnoreCase("Resultat")){
                            torn = receiveFromServer.readLine().trim();     
                            if (torn.equalsIgnoreCase("has guanyat")){
                                System.out.println("      @@ "+ torn + " @@");
                            }
                            else{
                                System.err.println("      @@ "+ torn + " @@");
                            }

                            return;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("Has desconectat.");
            return;

        default:
            break;
        }

    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: We would first need the stacktrace and the piece of the code where this issue is happening!

Comment: Per the API the exception is `"Thrown to indicate that there is an error creating or accessing a Socket."` -- you've got a bug in code that you've not yet shown us.

Comment: The code works when i execute the server and the clients in the same computer. It doesn't when server and clients in different pcs. The code is the same, why in one case it works and other case it just works half.

Comment: Because again, there is likely a bug in code not shown. If you can't find the bug, you're going to have to show the code.

Comment: 'Connection reset by peer' or just 'connection reset'? You must post the entire stack trace, as requested. And indicate which line throws the exception.

Comment: It is just conection reset. And the line is market with an arrow ->

Comment: For the third time, post the stack trace. Voting to close and downvoting.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't checking a single `readLine()` result for `null.` As a result, you have no hope of detecting a peer disconnect in the normal way. Every time you call `readLine()`, the first thing you must do is check for `null`, and if so close the socket and bail out.

Your exception handling is also poor. Code that depends on the success of code in a `try` block should be inside the same `try` block.

Comment: It's so rare, but when I execute my code in my house it dosn't work, but when I do this in the University internet it works.

This can be a router problem?

Comment: No, it's a coding problem. You're sending to a connection that has already been closed by the peer, and the defects I mentioned are preventing you from detecting this disconnection properly, so you're detecting it via this exception. Fix your code.

Comment: I know what u are saying, but I mean that i tryed to run it in my home (2 PC + 1 laptop) and it did not worked, conexion reset ERROR. But when i tryed it on the university (3 PCS), it worked as many times I runed it without any error. Why this happened?

Comment: It is pointless to enquire. Your code is invalid. Fix it along the lines we have discussed; re-test; report the results here; then we will discuss further.